# Pattern to match BBCode tags even if there are spaces or carriage returns?

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have the following possible strings

**Example A**

```
[attach]123[/attach]
[attach]456[/attach]
[attach]789[/attach]
```

**Example B**

```
[attach]123[/attach]

[attach]456[/attach]

[attach]789[/attach]
```

**Example C**

```
<space>
<carriage return>
[attach]123[/attach]
[attach]456[/attach]
[attach]789[/attach]
```

I need a regex pattern that would match the characters inside of the attach code, however the differences between the examples has to do with the spacing around each attach code, does regex simply ignore all the spacing and carriage return differences?   Can anyone help build a  preg_match?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you put your attempts at the problem in your question? Also, can you have nested tags? Like `[attach][b]123[/b][/attach]`?

Comment: @jerry this is what I tried so far, but it only matches the first line \[attach](.+?)\[\/attach]

Comment: Could you edit your question and put the code as you're using it? It might just be the way you're extracting the results. `preg_match_all` should get all the different numbers you're looking for.

Comment: @jerry you are correct, that did it!  Hah.  Can you create an answer and ill mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex should be working, albeit you can avoid the escaping using different delimiters, such as `~`:

```
preg_match_all('~\[attach\](.+?)\[/attach\]~i', $text, $matches);
```

[viper-7 demo](http://viper-7.com/3BVWM0)